# Boas práticas Asp.net Core MVC: Criar um DropDown para um registro corrente ser utilizado de forma global em todo o sistema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou com uma dúvida: Estou criando um sistema retaguarda em asp.net core mvc e no meu _Layout.cshtml preciso criar e carregar um dropdown listando todas as FILIAIS do sistema para que o usuário selecione a filial que ele desejar administrar. Essa filial selecionada deverá ser puxada em todas as telas do sistema... Um exemplo disso seria o CONTAS A PAGAR... Quando for lançado um registro, o campo filial será preenchido automaticamente como base na filial que estiver selecionada corrente.
Em aplicações Desktop isso é comum e muito fácil de se fazer, mas em webapp estou caindo de cabeça agora e apanhando muito...
Em teoria, como eu faria isso? Alguém teria algum exemplo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1 podia criar um componente!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Virgilio, mas a parte do carregamento eu entendi... Funciona como uma PartialView, mas não entendi como farei quando eu selecionar uma filial e ela ficar corrente para as telas utilizarem conforme na imagem que eu add acima de uma app Desktop...

Comment: Uma opção é salvar em `localstorage`..